# Constrained Optimization problem seemingly results in contradiction

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I am having issues with a constrained optimization problem that seems like it should be pretty simple. Here is the problem:

$f(x,y)=x^2-y^2;\hspace{.2 cm} x^2+y^2=25$

When I set up the system of equations, I get

$2x=2\lambda x, \hspace{0.2 cm} -2y=2\lambda y, \hspace{0.2 cm} x^2+y^2=25$

This seems to be a contradiction as equation 1 suggests $\lambda=1$ while the second equation suggests $\lambda=-1$. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: what if $x=0$ (or $y=0$)?

Comment: @JacksonAnderson Are you really required to use Lagrange multipliers? It seems an overkill in this case. Since $x^2 = 25-y^2$, we are just optimizing $25-2y^2$ with respect to $y$, when $y \in [-5,5]$.

Comment: Are you minimizing or maximizing $f(x,y)$?

Comment: When you look at $2x=2\lambda x$ and think "that implies $\lambda=1$", your pattern recognition instincts (thinking fast) are working, but I would recommend you practice thinking more slowly in math. If you have an equation with products of stuff in it, you really need to either: 1. procedurally move things to one side and factor or 2. Know on a conscious level that in order to cancel $x$ you have to divide by it, and when you divide by anything unknown you should worry about the case when you would be dividing by $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve the following system $x(\lambda+1)=y(\lambda-1)=0.$

We have no any contradiction here.

I think, it's better to make the following. $$x^2-y^2=x^2+y^2-2y^2=25-2y^2\leq25.$$
The equality occurs for $y=0$ and $x=5$, which says that we got a maximal value.

A minimal value we can get by the similar way:
$$x^2-y^2=2x^2-x^2-y^2=2x^2-25\geq-25.$$
Can you end it now?